# О происхождении слова «костенец»

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология названия папоротника *костенец*, русского названия рода Asplenium?

Comment: Тема интересна и, главное, актуальна. Но почему она стала интересна автору? Если вопрос сформулировать (для начала), то проще будет и ответить на него.

Comment: Причина очень простая: я филолог, и этимология названий меня интересует априори. У меня есть хороший знакомый - птеридолог из Германии, он просил меня объяснить происхождение русского названия рода Asplenium.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Костене́ц  — перевод латинского названия Holósteum — название рода от др.-греч. ὅλος — «целый» и ὀστέον — «кость», то есть «Цельнокостница». По названию можно было бы ожидать, что растение очень твёрдое, но оно названо по принципу антифразы, в противоположность его свойствам. Это,действительно,не папоротник, это цветковое растение и достаточно мягкое.

А вот папоротник как раз твёрдый, по крайней мере этого рода.Черешок прямой и твёрдый, и к нему по всей длине крепятся  листья - обычно перистые, даже у листовидного кое-где прорезанные, по-моему, очень похоже на кости (хребет) рыбы, если с них мясо снять. Может, поэтому такое русское название?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос (как мне кажется) не совсем для сайта русского языка. Но хочу обратить внимание на то, что [**костенец**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) ( (лат. *Holósteum*), про который говорит @Людмила, — род травянистых растений семейства гвоздичные (т.е. цветковое растение, а не папоротник).

[**Костенец**](http://kvetok.ru/komnatnye-rasteniya/asplenium-kostenets), или костяне́ц, или аспле́ний, или аспле́ниум (лат. *Asplénium*) — род папоротников семейства костенцовые.
Само название *асплениум* имеет греческое происхождение и переводится как **а** — «не», **splen** – «селезенка». Предполагалось, что папоротник этого вида имеет соответствующие медицинские свойства, отсюда и такое имя (какие именно свойства  — у меня информации нет).
[В энциклопедическом словаре Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона:
Асплениум
(Asplenium L.), селезеночник, кочедыжник...]

Упоминание и одного, и другого растения есть у [**Даля**](https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) в статье *КОСТЬ*:
*Костеник, вещь, сделанная из одной, цельной кости; сплошное зерно, **косточка растен**., напр. финиковое. **Костенец** м. растен. Stellaria holostea; | Ноlosteum; | Аsplenium.*

**Дополнение**

Спорангии, в которых развиваются споры костенца, расположены на тыльной стороне листьев, создавая коричневое окрашивание пластинки.
Думаю, название "костенец" и связано с тем, что по виду они напоминают [**маленькие косточки**](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=0z534Yv%2F&id=B7068A77F050C9FB14479A0056CAD858EA3BF151&thid=OIP.0z534Yv_1ROM92KB3BYzhwEyDL&q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86&simid=607996366902265642&selectedIndex=28&qpvt=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86&ajaxhist=0).